Can we use convnets to learn the masked letter in a word?
I'm interested in training a CNN to learn the relationship between a word with a single masked letter and that masked letter. For example, if my model is $M$ and the input is "he-lo", it should predict "l" because the missing letter is "l". Note: I am masking a single letter in the word.
Similar questions have been asked but, to my knowledge, not answered in-depth: Predicting missing letters in a word
This task does seem similar to how Transformers are trained with masking words. However, predicting a single masked letter should intuitively be much easier and be solvable with a much simpler architecture.
I am currently representing words as vectors with shape $1 x N$ where $N$ is the length of the word and each entry corresponds to the character's index in the alphabet, i.e. 'ab-' would be represented as [0, 1, -1].
My model architecture is an embedding layer with embedding dimension equal to $27$, two stacked convolutional layer + max pooling layer, after which there is a flattening layer, followed by a dense layer and finally a softmax output layer indicating which of the 26 letters the model predicts the masked character to be. See below for the code implementation.
My current issue: Despite having over 1M training samples, my model is stalling at around 41% accuracy (defined as the character with the largest predicted probability matching the correct character output for that input). Is there a flaw with my model? Am I underestimating the complexity of this task and the model is actually performing fairly well? Any advice or feedback is appreciated.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Dense, Input, Masking, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
def getModel():
    input_shape = (29,)
    num_classes=26
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Embedding(input_dim=29, output_dim=27, input_length=None)(inputs)
    x = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x) 
    x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    custom_adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.003, beta_1=0.99, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07)
    model.compile(optimizer=custom_adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model


If you're asking whether there is any literature or publciations that have researched this task, then this is an on-topic question. But if you're asking an open-ended question where people will train some model and report their results, then this is not an on-topic question. You've trained on model on some corpus and found a certain result; if you're not satisfied with that result, you'll need to train more models and/or gather more data -- this is, essentially, the entire job of a data scientist or neural networks researcher.

I don't expect anyone to train their own model from my question. For plenty of tasks, there are common architectures that tend to work and others that don't. I'm asking if my model setup is appropriate for the task.

A published resource is where that information would be found. So you should just state in your question you’re asking if there are published results — the code is entirely immaterial to that. Also, if you have a particular reason for trying to do this, sharing that would help people understand what you're trying to do and why. That could help articulate a better solution.
